# Can I not use jquery to set the html for label tag?

Tags: php, jquery

I am learning to write a quiz application using only jquery and PHP, no databases.

I use PHP to prepare the structure of the HTML file. And then using jquery to fill up the data.

The question gets displayed fine. But the label tags of the options remain undefined.

**The script:**

```js
var questions = [
 {
  
  "statement": "The function <img src='images/1.png'>, where [x] denotes the greatest integer function, is defined for all x &straightepsilon;",
  "ans1": "R",
  "ans2": "R - {(-1, 1) U n: n &straightepsilon; I }",
  "ans3": "R<sup>+</sup> - (0, 1)",
  "ans4": "R - (n: n &straightepsilon; N)",
 }
];

$(document).ready(function() {
 var i = 0;
 var j  = 1;
 while (i < questions.length) {
  $("#question" + j).html('Q' + j + ". " + questions[i]["statement"]);
  // the labels //
  $("#question" + j + "-choice1").html(questions[i]["ans1"]);
  //console.log($("#question" + j + "-choice1").html());
  console.log(questions[i]["ans1"]);
  $("#question" + j + "-choice2").html(questions[i]["ans2"]);
  $("#question" + j + "-choice3").html(questions[i]["ans3"]);
  $("#question" + j + "-choice4").html(questions[i]["ans4"]);
  
  i++;
  j++;
 }
});
```

Here's the php script I am using to create the markup.

```
<?php

    $numQues = 30; // max number of questions.
    $i = 1;

    while ($i <= $numQues) {

        // careful with this string generator :) 
        echo '<div class="questions">
              <p id="question' . $i . '"'. '></p>'.
              '<input type="radio" name="ans' . $i .''. '><label id="question' . $i . '-choice1' .'"></label><br>'.
             '<input type="radio" name="ans'. $i . '><label id="question' . $i . '-choice2' . '"></label><br>'.
              '<input type="radio" name="ans'. $i . '><label id="question'. $i .'-choice3'.'"'.'></label><br>'.
              '<input type="radio" name="ans' . $i . '><label id="question'. $i .'-choice4'.'"'.'></label><br>'.
              '<button class="btn btn-primary pull-right" id="question-review'. $i . '"'. '>Mark for Review</button>
              </div>';

        $i++;

    }

?>
```

Comment: You're missing the double-quote characters at the end of the `name` attributes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing lots of double-quote characters. E.g.

```
'<input type="radio" name="ans'. $i . '><label id="question' . $i . '-choice2' . '"></label><br>'.
```

should be

```
'<input type="radio" name="ans'. $i . '"><label id="question' . $i . '-choice2' . '"></label><br>'.
                                       ^
```

Because of this, it's setting the name to something like `"ans1><label id="`, and not recognizing `<label>` as a new tag.

Instead of all the trouble-prone concatenation, you can use variable interpolation inside a double-quoted string:

```
    echo "<div class='questions'>
          <p id='question$i'></p>
          <input type='radio' name='ans$i'><label id='question$i-choice1'></label><br>
          <input type='radio' name='ans$i'><label id='question$i-choice2'></label><br>
          <input type='radio' name='ans$i'><label id='question$i-choice3'></label><br>
          <input type='radio' name='ans$i'><label id='question$i-choice4'></label><br>
          <button class='btn btn-primary pull-right' id='question-review$i'>Mark for Review</button>
          </div>";
```

I changed the quotes in the HTML elements to single quotes so I don't need to escape them.

Another popular method is to output normal HTML, and then use `<?php echo $variable ?>` in the places where you need to substitute a variable.

```
    while ($i <= $numQues) {
      ?>
      <div class="questions">
      <p id="question<?php echo $i; ?>"></p>
      <input type="radio" name="ans<?php echo $i; ?>"><label id="question<?php echo $i; ?>-choice1"></label><br>
      <input type="radio" name="ans<?php echo $i; ?>"><label id="question<?php echo $i; ?>-choice2"></label><br>
      <input type="radio" name="ans<?php echo $i; ?>"><label id="question<?php echo $i; ?>-choice3"></label><br>
      <input type="radio" name="ans<?php echo $i; ?>"><label id="question<?php echo $i; ?>-choice4"></label><br>
      <button class="btn btn-primary pull-right" id="question-review<?php echo $i; ?>">Mark for Review</button>
      </div>
      <?
      $i++;
  }
```

Comment: It worked. Can you suggest a better method to form such strings or should I just be more careful? Many thanks.

Comment: I've added my preferred style using variable interpolation instead of concatenation.